# Авторизация на сессиях

Tags: сессия, авторизация, php

Уважаемые форумчане. Писал админку для сайта, и наткнулся на проблему с авторизацией. Для начала небольшая структура сайта + код.

Заранее попрошу не критиковать мой метод написания, а просто помочь с решением, где у меня ошибка, или что можно изменить, не меняя организационную структуру сайта.

Всё начинается со страницы admin.php:

```
require 'includes/common.php';
require 'includes/pages/admin/class.AbstractPage.php';

$page       = HTTP::_GP('page', 'general');
$mode       = HTTP::_GP('mode', 'show');
$page       = str_replace(array('_', '\\', '/', '.', "\0"), '', $page);
$pageClass  = 'Show'.ucwords($page).'Page';

if(!file_exists('includes/pages/admin/class.'.$pageClass.'.php')) {
    echo "Страница не существует! 15";
}

require('includes/pages/admin/class.'.$pageClass.'.php');

$pageObj    = new $pageClass;

if(!is_callable(array($pageObj, $mode)))
    $mode   = 'show';

$pageObj->{$mode}();
```

Как видим в самом начале подключается файл `common.php`. Кроме всего прочего нас интересует там данный код:

```
require('includes/classes/class.Session.php');
$SESSION = new Session();
```

Дальше, в файле `admin.php` подключается файл страницы, и из него присваивается определённый класс. Вот код страницы авторизации:

```
class ShowLoginPage extends AbstractPage
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function show()
    {
        echo "login: ".$_SESSION['login']."<br />pass: ".$_SESSION['pass']."<br />status: ".$_SESSION['status'];
    }

    function login()
    {
        $login     = HTTP::_GP('login', '');
        $pwd       = crypt(HTTP::_GP('password', ''), '$2a$07$rZfG5Hp67QWng64KlwqFhT$');

        if(!$GLOBALS['SESSION']->verify($login, $pwd)){
            echo "Ошибочка вышла. Вы парольчик-то проверьте... <img src='http://mass.xterium.ru/styles/images/smails/crazy.gif'>";
            return;
        }else
            echo "login: ".$_SESSION['login']."<br />pass: ".$_SESSION['pass']."<br />status: ".$_SESSION['status'];
    }
}
```

Как видите, при авторизации вызывается класс, запускающий сессию:

```
class Session
{
    function check()
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
            return false;
        }

        if($_SESSION['status'] == false)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    static function create($login, $pwd)
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_start();
        }

        $_SESSION['login']      = $login;
        $_SESSION['pwd']        = $pwd;
        $_SESSION['status']     = true;
    }

    function verify($login, $pwd)
    {
        $count = $GLOBALS['DATABASE']->countquery("SELECT * FROM `".USERS."` WHERE `login` = '".$login."' AND `pwd` = '".$pwd."';");
        if($count == 0)
            return false;
        else{
            $this->create($login, $pwd);
            return true;
        }
    }

    function destroy()
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Что интересно: я отправляю на страницу авторизации данные (функция `login()`). Эти данные пихаются в функцию `verify()` в классе `Session`. Проверяется, даётся отмашка `true`, и выводится на экран информация о сессии. Отлично. Но когда я после этого загружаю страницу авторизации с функцией `show()`, то данные о сессии не выводятся - вылетает ошибка, об отсутствии переменных в глобальном массиве `$_SESSION`. У меня возникла мысля, что это из-за того, что глобальная переменная меняется в функции, а не в основном коде. Глобальное значение не меняется, а меняется только внутреннее. Что интересно, в аналогичном коде, используется именно этот метод авторизации на сессиях, и всё работает. Разве что там в классе сессии, в функции `create()` небольшое отличие есть:

```
static function create($login, $pwd)
{
    self::$obj = new self;

    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

    $_SESSION['login']     = $login;
    $_SESSION['pwd']       = $pwd;
    $_SESSION['status']    = true;

    return self::$obj;
}
```

Проверял: использование `self::$obj = new self;` и `return self::$obj;` проблему не решает.

P.S.: напомню - прошу не критиковать мой метод написания сайта, а по существу помочь. :)

Заранее всем спасибо. :)

---

Небольшое дополнение. В движке, на который я ориентируюсь при написании своего, файл сессий содержит такой текст, и всё работает:

```
class Session
{
    private static $obj;
    private static $isInit = false;

    static function init() {
        ini_set('session.use_cookies', '1');
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '1');
        ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
        ini_set('session.auto_start', '0');
        ini_set('session.serialize_handler', 'php');  
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', SESSION_LIFETIME);
        ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
        ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1000');
        ini_set('session.bug_compat_warn', '0');
        ini_set('session.bug_compat_42', '0');
        ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', true);

        $HTTP_ROOT = MODE === 'INSTALL' ? dirname(HTTP_ROOT) : HTTP_ROOT;

        session_set_cookie_params(SESSION_LIFETIME, $HTTP_ROOT, NULL, HTTPS, true);
        session_cache_limiter('nocache');
        session_name('2Moons');
        self::$isInit   = true;
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        if(self::$isInit === false)
        {
            self::init();
        }
    }

    static function create($userID, $planetID = 0)
    {
        self::$obj  = new self;

        if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_start();
        }

        $_SESSION['id']         = $userID;
        $_SESSION['agent']      = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $_SESSION['planet']     = $planetID;

        return self::$obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: `session_start()` в начале файла должен быть установлен, дальше когда пользователь авторизируется в конструкторе заносите его логин и пасс в переменную класса, далее работаете с этой переменной, в том же Kohana Auth весь объект заносится и весьма удобно. Может вам это не понятно? Кстати, не забывайте дебажить ваши данные: `var_dump($_SESSION)` и т.п., очень помогает в разработке.

Comment: @Smash, за ответ спасибо, но я немного не понял порядоке действий, и зачем добавлять ещё одну переменную? Мне нужна именно глобальная. Прочтите дополнение у вопросу. Я дописал. Внизу вопроса, отделил чертой. :)

Comment: ну если пользователь залогинился, то занести его данные в конструкторе самого базового класса в переменную этого класса, если не получилось, то проследите почему через дебаг, я напр. тоже не пойму к чему эти все глобалс...

    // Handled from a form with inputs with names email / password
    $post = $this->request->post();
    $success = Auth::instance()->login($post['email'],     $post['password']);
 
    if ($success)
    {
        // Login successful, send to app
    }
    else
    {
        // Login failed, send back to form with error message
    }

Comment: Вот так это сделано в [Kohana 3.3 Module Auth][1]

[1]: http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/auth/login

Comment: Может я что-то не понимаю, но в конструктор основного класса врядли получится эти данные забить. Так как страниц у меня масса. Да и страница `admin.php` не является классом. :)

Мне надо именно на Сессиях авторизироваться. Не на каких-то созданных мною переменных, а на сессиях.

Comment: ну суть то та же, не важно где в сессию занести, главное проверить в базовом классе. Ну а далее уже смотреть по страницам где пропадают данные.

Comment: @Smash Ну я посмотрел тот код из коханы, но честно - я ничего не могу понять. Ни разъяснений, ничего. Где именно этот код записан, при каких условиях он выполняется. Мне нужно, чтоб логинилось при входе на страницу. И к тому же - не думаю что данные просто пропадают. Мне кажется, что глобально они не устанавливаются в моём случае, а устанавливаются на уровне одной функции.

Comment: Чёрт. И тишина. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, ответ найден. Пришлось долго и мучительно курить мануалы, читать доки и в конце просидеть с товарищем полтора часа над моим кодом. Недочёт был выявлен, а также мы с товарищем по-смеялись, что недочёт мелкий, а проблем создавал кучу.

Проблему решило добавление конструктора в класс сессий:

```
function __construct()
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }
}
```

Если почитать на просторах интернета, то вы можете наткнуться на совет, о котором вежливо умолчал пост о сессиях на хабре: сессию надо открывать на каждой странице где она используется. Я же думал достаточно один раз объявить и всё. А нет, оказывается! Ну в общем я проблему решил, всем огромное спасибо за внимание. :)